# How to change <span> text in CSS media query

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the text inside a `<span>` element within a media query, and I want to avoid using JavaScript if possible. Is there a way to do this with only HTML/CSS?

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header .text-1 {
    /* property here? */
  }
  header .text-2 {
    /* property here? */
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <span class="text-1">COLMAR</span>
    <!-- change to "C" -->
    <span class="text-2">ACADEMY</span>
    <!-- change to "A" -->
  </div>
</header>
```

When the window is less than 768px wide, I want the two `<span>`s in the `<header>` to be abbreviated to just one character ("C" and "A").

I looked on [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_gen_content.asp) for a property that would do this, something similar to (I think) JavaScript's `.innerHtml`, and I found `content`, but it doesn't seem to do what I am looking for.

I am willing to use JavaScript if necessary, I just want to avoid it if it only takes a couple lines in CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another approach using the `::before` pseudo element as well (plus the original content wrapped in another span), but using a custom data attribute to define the alternative text instead of having to add a class for each occurrence. This allows to fill in the text via a CMS for example.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-alttext] > span {
    display: none;
  }
  
  [data-alttext]::before {
    content: attr(data-alttext);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <span class="text-1" data-alttext="C"><span>COLMAR</span></span> <!-- change to "C" -->
    <span class="text-2" data-alttext="A"><span>ACADEMY</span></span> <!-- change to "A" -->
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Excellent approach! I had used this a while back myself but was drawing blanks when it came time to answer this question. Relied on muscle memory with `:before` lol.

Comment: This is intriguing, and I copy/pasted the code, but it doesn't seem to be working. It seems to have duplicated the text of each `<span>` (screenshot [here](https://i.gyazo.com/f55e7388944d7142dbc81d25146c20ea.png)).

Comment: Please post a working example demonstrating your problem on jsbin or codepen. I can't debug from a screenshot, and the code works perfectly well in the code snippet I provided.

Comment: I opened up a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OYLgjN), and now what I try is working. I currently have Jennifer Goncalves' example set up, and it works. Just realized that Chrome emulation is broken, and that's the issue. Sorry for the waste of time, but thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the pseudo selector `:before` as so:

```css
header .text-1:before {
  content: "COLMAR";
}

header .text-2:before {
  content: "ACADEMY";
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header .text-1:before {
    content: "C";
  }
  
  header .text-2:before {
    content: "A";
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <span class="text-1"></span> <!-- change to "C" -->
    <span class="text-2"></span> <!-- change to "A" -->
  </div>
</header>
```

After doing a little bit of [research](https://tink.uk/accessibility-support-for-css-generated-content/) you don't lose any accessibility with this approach either.

Comment: Just tried this, and it's not working for some reason, and I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: You copied this answer verbatim?

Comment: Yeah, I copied it and double checked everything.

Comment: Weird. Are you adjusting your screen to actually see the change?

Comment: I am using emulation in Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: I put a sample in codepen and it works; I think something is wrong with Chrome emulation, I have to manually scale the window. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could set the width of the `span` tag in CSS.  For the width to be able to be used, you need `display:block;`.  You use `overflow:none;` to hide the rest of the text.

The width of the span will have to depend on font size and font family.  Using a monospace font will help as all the characters are the same width.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header .text-1,
  header .text-2{
  width: 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <span class="text-1">COLMAR</span>
    <!-- change to "C" -->
    <span class="text-2">ACADEMY</span>
    <!-- change to "A" -->
  </div>
</header>
```